# Mercadopago v3 php sdk

Tags: php, mercadopago, sdk

estoy tratando de implementar en php probe la v3.0.2 y nada baje a la 2 y tampoco, este es
mi codigo:

```
<?php
// $accesstoken='Test123';//no comparto por cuestiones de seguridad
require _DIR.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use MercadoPago\MercadoPagoConfig;
// use MercadoPago\PreferenceClient;
// Agrega credenciales
$access_token='Test123';//por razones de seguridad no comparto
MercadoPagoConfig::setAccessToken($access_token);


// MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken($access_token);
// $client = new PreferenceClient();
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
$preference = $client->create([
  "items"=> array(
    array(
      "title" => "Suscripcion La Pizarra",
      "quantity" => 1,
      "unit_price" => 10000
    )
  )
]);
```

No funciona y me da error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MercadoPago\MercadoPagoConfig" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mercadopago\index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mercadopago\index.php on line 8

Comment: `require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';` puede ser que a la constante mágica `__DIR__` en el path le faltan unos `__` y  no estaría cargando el autoload, o el autoload le falta regenerarse con un `composer install`

Comment: perdon no me di cuenta al copiar tengo bien esa parte no funcionaba ahora cambie la parte de setaccesstoken:

MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken($access_token);

$client = new PreferenceClient();

$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();

pero me dice :
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MercadoPago\PreferenceClient" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mercadopago\index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mercadopago\index.php on line 13

Comment: cuando se pone asi lo mas conveniente suele ser borrar la carpeta vendor y darle al composer install nuevamente

Comment: Lo 1º que conviene saber es cuál es tu versión de PHP. Si estás en la versión 8.2 o superior, entonces instala la última versión del SDK mediante `composer require "mercadopago/dx-php:3.0.2"`, luego, implementa el código [tal y como viene explicado en la documentación](https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-php). En cambio, si estás en PHP 7.1, tienes que ejecutar `composer require "mercadopago/dx-php:2.6.1"` o, si estás en PHP 5.6 (Dios no lo quiera), tienes que ejecutar `composer require "mercadopago/dx-php:1.12.5"`. En cualquier caso, tienes que usar el código propio de la versión que instales.

Answer (score 0):

Hola pongo la solución del código que me anduvo (renderizó el botón de pagar y la pasarela de pagos) la version de php es 8.2 y tuve que bajar en el composer.json a v2.0 lo cual instalo mercadopago 2.6.1, este es el codigo que anduvo:

```
    <?php
    $access_token='TEST-123';
    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    use MercadoPago\MercadoPagoConfig;
    use MercadoPago\PreferenceClient;
    MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken($access_token);
    $preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
    $preference->back_urls=array(
    "success"=> "https://localhost/mercadopago/ok.php",
    "failure"=> "https://localhost/mercadopago/fail.php",
    "pending"=> "https://localhost/mercadopago/fail.php",
);
$preference->auto_return = "approved";

$productos=[];
$item = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item->title = "Suscripcion La Pizarra";
$item->quantity = 1;
$item->unit_price=10000;
array_push($productos,$item);
$preference->items=$productos;
$preference->save();
?>
```

Gracias a los que contribuyeron :) de igual manera tengo que implementar suscripciones así que debo seguir investigando.